# Do we need the "engineer" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have a [engineer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineer) with 7 questions.

Do we really need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what the [engineer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineer) tag is supposed to mean, and the questions currently tagged with it don't really seem to have anything in common. Specifically, there are:

- 2 questions about flight test engineers.
- 1 question about aerodynamics.
- 1 question about aircraft building plans.
- 1 question about mechanics (the occupation).
- 2 questions about electrical engineering as applied to avionics.

So I don't see any reason to keep the tag.

(The [flight-engineer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-engineer) tag, on the other hand, does seem like it may be useful, so let's keep it. Maybe we should apply it to more questions, even.)

Answer (score 1):

No we don't. There are multiple engineering disciplines involved in aviation, most of which have dedicated field/topic tags, such as structures, avionics, propulsion, aerodynamics, etc.

And since career advice is both too broad and opinion based, using the tag for such purposes combined with a topic-tag is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

We do have [pilots](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pilots) so maybe we'll have a similar use for [engineer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineer) on future questions but right now it doesn't seem to be very useful. There are only a couple questions there that seem to really fit the tag at all and [career](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) seems like it is close enough for most use cases.